# How many viewer/subcriber will be consider if same user open the webpage in two different tabs, connecting to a session?

Tags: opentok, tokbox, vonage

I have just came across a usecase in which same user (or user with same token) have to connect the session twice, what actually I found everything is working fine. But still curious to know.

In tokbox, if a user joins with two different tabs that is same token what will be happened at server end of tokbox and will it be consider two different viewer?

Answer (score 1):

This will be two connections within the session - so different "viewers", yes. Each connection will be publishing and subscribing-to its own streams, so could be doing different things. This is unusual use case (which typically causes audio feedback etc.) so make sure this is what you really want in your design.